# Remount drive without physically disconnecting?

Tags: macos, usb

So I have unmounted a usb external hard drive but I went to re-mount it.  Is there a command that I can use to remount the drive?  Only way I know to re-mount a drive is to disconnect the usb cable from my Mac and reconnect it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One-liner:

```
diskutil mount `diskutil list | grep "Volume Name" | sed -n -e 's/^.* //p'`
```

---

1. Find the disk identifier:

   ```
   diskutil list | grep "Volume Name"
   ```

   <sub>Example result:</sub>

   ```
   4:   Apple_HFS Volume Name   100 GB   disk1s2
   ```
2. Mount the disk:

   ```
   diskutil mount disk1s2
   ```

Answer (score 24):

Disk Utility will let you remount any connected drives. Just

1. open it up (It is usually in Applications > Utilities)
2. select the drive
3. click "Mount"

Comment: All there years of using Disk Utility I never knew you could do this :)

Answer (score 8):

`diskutil mount` also accepts a volume name, so there is no need to grep the output of `diskutil list`. If the disk has multiple volumes (like a Time Machine volume and another volume), you can use `diskutil mountDisk` to mount all volumes:

```
$ diskutil mount WD
Volume WD on WD mounted
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to disks where ejectable is true'
disk WD
$ diskutil eject Untitled
Disk WD ejected
$ diskutil mountDisk WD
Volume(s) mounted successfully
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to disks where ejectable is true'
disk Time Machine, disk WD
```

`mountDisk` and `eject` apply to all volumes even if you specify the name of one volume.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate easy solution: In place of ejecting drive you should unmount it, and when needed mount it again.

Unmount / mount: <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> (Spotlight search) > Disk utility > Select drive > unmount / mount

After unmount, it's also safe to remove disk physically.

Comment: On my computer Disk Utility does show up in that search, but there are a whole bunch of files that show up in the results too...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers already given, there is also a GUI app for this, which I really like: [Mountain](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mountain/id528726140?mt=12).

It's a $2 app that sits in the menu bar and keeps track of both mounted and unmounted drives. Unmounted drives can be remounted from there as well.

You can [download a free trial](http://appgineers.de/mountain/) from the website.

(Also note that once you install the Mac App Store version, there is an update available directly from the developer. I assume the update isn't on the Mac App Store because of Apple's sandboxing rules.)