# How to mount by SOFTWARE a USB SSD that shows not mounted on Mac?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, mount, software

How to mount by **SOFTWARE** a USB SSD that shows not mounted on Mac?

System: macOS 10.12.6 (16G2136) Sierra. If the USB SSD is connected before rebooting or cold booting the Mac, then it shows. If the Mac is booted from an external USB SSD, no problem (after booting or rebooting, the afterwards plugged USB SSD show). But if the Mac is booted from the internal SSD, then plugging afterwards an external USB SSD does not mount it. Unplugging and plugging it again (or plugging other USB SSD in other USB port; sometimes requiring more than one trial) fixes it for such SSD and any other until the Mac is rebooted or booted, in which case the same issue arises.

The USB disk not mounted does not show in Disk Utility or Mountain. Using Terminal “diskutil list” does not show it. It does not show in "Apple - About This Mac - System Report - Hardware - Storage", but shows on the latter selecting “…–Hardware - USB". Other formatting, maintenance, repair or recovery utilities do not show such unmounted USB SSD until it shows mounted on the Desktop.

Thanks!

Comment: We may need to untangle the question a bit. Are you basically saying that you have an external SSD which sometimes isn't recognized by the system after you plug it in?

Comment: Also, this seems to be very similar to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127677/software-only-way-to-disconnect-and-reconnect-a-usb-device. Did you try the accepted answer there, what was the result?

Comment: Thanks. Answers: 1. It is recognized if previously plugged before rebooting or cold booting. But it is not recognized if pugged after rebooting or cold booting, unless I do as described. 2. Yes, I tried to post there to say that it did not work, since /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.displaylink.displaylinkmanager.plist does not exist in macOS macOS 10.12.6 (16G2136) Sierra, yet was not allowed to post such message because it was not an answer. Therefore, I created a new thread.

Comment: This is also similar, but did not work because when I try to run the code starting with /*! @function USBDeviceReEnumerate in Script Editor, I get Syntax Error. I could not reply there for for same reason indicated above. Such article is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786922/programmatically-unplug-and-replug-a-usb-device-to-load-new-driver-in-os-x

Comment: There is another answer which unloads/loads a kext. Did you try? Also if the drive sometimes gets recognized and sometimes not, did you replace the cable already?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried all that is indicated in the two articles above. The cable is OK. Actually, I have tested dozens of cables and dozens of external USB SSD, and all behave like that. No problem with Thunderbolt SSD. Once the first external USB SSD mounts, all the rest mount until the Mac is rebooted or cold booted with the disks not plugged.

Comment: Then, plugging the first one start the issue again, And so on for months testing. Actually, the issue arose after updating macOS 10.12.6 (16G2128) to (16G2136) Sierra on 27th September 2017, more than three years ago. No problem before.

Comment: So, it seems a macOS bug, but since it will not be fixed by Apple for such macOS version, I am looking for a way to somehow reset the USB bus or mount-unmount-mount by software, to prevent having to unplug and plug external SSD live, which could cause data loss and even hardware failure if done while the disk is actually connected and about to mount in a second when the user thinks that it is not, etc.

Comment: TO ADMINS. I have posted several comments in a row, since this web form does not allow longer text and not even carriage returns. It would be convenient if that was allowed. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of adding details in comments please **edit** your question to include additional information.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it.  https://superuser.com/questions/1603345/how-to-mount-on-mac-by-software-a-usb-ssd-that-shows-not-mounted

Comment: Sorry about that. I posted here because I was advised to do it in the other site.