# Programatically disconnecting/reconnecting Yubikey device

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, command-line, usb

I have a:
MacBookPro 16"
OS 12.3

and I have a "YubiKey 5C Nano".

each time my device goes to sleep the key stops responding, and disconnecting + reconnecting is a hassle

found similar issues:

- [Software-only way to disconnect and reconnect a USB device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/127677)
- [Remount drive without physically disconnecting?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125854)

asked on a GH repo and got turned down:

- https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl/issues/372

any help + debugging this would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Having the same issue on a Mac Studio running MacOS 14.4.1. Have you been able to find a solution to this? I noticed that running the YubiKey Manager software, will make the device to work again without unplugging and reconnecting it.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion you got on GitHub is probably the easiest way to go for a quick fix: I.e. add a supported USB hub to the system, plug the YubiKey in the USB hub - and if your problem hasn't gone away already, you can use `uhubctl` to restart the YubiKey.

Apart from that, I would contact YubiKey support and let them know you have this issue with their product.

Comment: this might be ok, but sadly I do not have a usb hub that allows me to operate the yubikey.
if we have a better way of doing this it'll be great

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "usb hub that allows me to operate the yubikey" - I just wanted to be sure that you know that any USB hub should allow you to use a YubiKey. They do not have any special requirements in terms of USB hubs.